# A graph obtained by adding new vertices to be $k$-connected

Tags: graph-theory

Is the following  true and ,if yes, how does it follow from  Menger's theorem ?

Let $G$ be a $k$-connected graph and let $v$ be a vertex of $G$. For a positive integer $t$, define $G_t$ to be the graph obtained from $G$ by adding $t$ new vertices $u_1, u_2,..., u_t$ and all edges of the form $u_iw$, where $1 \leq i \leq t$  and for which $vw$ belongs to $E(G)$, Show that $G_t$ is $k$-connected

Comment: $G_t$ will be at least $k$-connected, but it might be more connected than $G$ if $v$ was a vertex whose removal would decrease the connectedness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $G$ is $k$-connected, the degree of $v$ is at least $k$. Therefore, in $G_t$, the degree of each $u_i$ is also at least $k$. We can employ the following known lemma to prove $G_t$ is $k$-connected.

> **Lemma.** Let $G$ be a $k$-connected graph. If $G'$ is obtained from $G$ by adding a new vertex $x$
>   adjacent to at least $k$ vertices of $G$, then $G'$ is $k$-connected.

By this lemma, after adding vertex $u_1$ and the associated edges, the resulting graph is $k$-connected. We can further add other vertices in $\{u_2, \cdots, u_t\}$ one by one and apply the lemma to reach the conclusion.